# Portable way to change Prolog atom JSON escaping

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, unicode-escapes

Is there a portable way to change the Prolog escaping. I
have the following in mind, usualy an atom is escaped as
follows, for example using octal escaping:

```
/* SWI-Prolog 8.3.23 */

?- X = 'abc\x0001\def'.
X = 'abc\001\def'.
```

But what I want to archive, is an output as follows.
If a compound `'$STR'/1` is used, the escape should
be `"\uXXXX"` instead of octal escaping and double quotes:

```
?- X = '$STR'('abc\x0001\def').
X = "abc\u0001def".
```

Do Prolog systems have some hook, like portray, that
could do that? I do not expect approaches based on ISO
core standard, already `"\uXXXX"` isn't ISO core standard

Answer (score 0):

A portable way would be to use write/1 instead of writeq/1, and convert the atom itself before using write/1. A conversion code can use the ISO core standard atom_codes/2 as follows:

```
% escape_atom(+Atom, -Atom)
escape_atom(X, Y) :-
   atom_codes(X, L),
   escape_codes(L, R, [0'"]),
   atom_codes(Y, [0'"|R]).
```

The predicate escape_codes/2 itself can be easily implemented with DCG, which is also available for many Prolog systems. Surrogate pairs can be extracted as follows, using standard arithmetic:

```
% high_surrogate(+Integer, -Integer)
high_surrogate(X, Y) :- Y is (X >> 10) + 0xD7C0.

% low_surrogate(+Integer, -Integer)
low_surrogate(X, Y) :- Y is (X /\ 0x3FF) + 0xDC00.
```

Here is an example run of the routine:

```
?- escape_atom('abc\x1000c\def', X), write(X), nl.
"abc\ud800\udc0cdef"
X = '"abc\\ud800\\udc0cdef"'
?- escape_atom('abc\x1000b\def', X), write(X), nl.
"abcdef"
X = '"abcdef"'
```

The only missing piece is a built-in code_type/2 that is supposed to deliver the unicode general category of a code point. This is then used to identify control codes and invalid codes,

only these are escaped.

**Open Source: Prolog escape.pl**
https://gist.github.com/jburse/bf6c01c7524f2611d606cb88983da9d6#file-escape-pl